Accessing interleaved struct-like data from a TypedArray, without multiple reads?
This is a performance-related question. As such, regular JS rules and conventions are irrelevant here. Note also that JS objects are not in any way performance-equivalent to C structs, particularly those allocated in AoS format. Thank you for your understanding.
In C, we read or write large structs' data fast by pulling a struct instance from an array of struct into a local variable, modifying it, and writing that (as a value) directly back into the array again by simple assignment. The struct can be up to some platform-specified limit, usually up to several thousand bytes. This makes for both easy and super-fast handling of data. Disassembly may show some fast memcpy type stuff happening under the hood to achieve this. C example:
struct MyStruct arrayOfStructs[]; //on stack for simplicity
//...populate the Array-of-Struct with some data...

//copy out the struct we want, onto the stack:
struct MyStruct structValue = arrayOfStructs[i];

//...change the structValue's members
structValue.x = 12;
structValue.y = 3;

//assign it back by value, rather than memberwise.
arrayOfStructs[i] = structValue;

The benefit here is that no matter how large the struct is, we write it back in a single line, and the compiler handles the copying needed to make that happen as quickly as possible.
In Javascript, the only performant alternative is to use (Typed)Arrays. We fake our "struct" thus:
const SIZEOF_X = 1; //1 byte
const SIZEOF_Y = 1; //1 byte
const SIZEOF_Z = 1; //1 byte
const SIZEOF_PADDING0 = 1; //1 byte padding, aligns following members to 4B heap boundaries.
const SIZEOF_PAYLOAD1 = 2; //2 bytes
const SIZEOF_PAYLOAD2 = 2; //2 bytes

const SIZEOF_BYTES_ENTITY = 
                      SIZEOF_X +
                      SIZEOF_Y + 
                      SIZEOF_Z + 
                      SIZEOF_PADDING0 + 
                      SIZEOF_PAYLOAD1 +
                      SIZEOF_PAYLOAD2; //8 bytes total.

//calculating offsets into the "struct" can be done using a loop, but for clarity:
const OFFSET_BYTES_X = 0;
const OFFSET_BYTES_Y = SIZEOF_BYTES_X;
const OFFSET_BYTES_Z = SIZEOF_BYTES_X + SIZEOF_BYTES_Y;
//...etc.

const buffer = new ArrayBuffer(ENTITIES_COUNT * SIZEOF_BYTES_ENTITY);
const structsAs64 = new Uint64Array(buffer); //Uint64 because one struct = 8B.
const structsAs16 = new Uint16Array(buffer);
const structsAs8  = new  Uint8Array(buffer);
//...populate our underlying buffer with some data... (not shown)

const structValue64 = structsAs64[i]; 
const z = structValue64 >> OFFSET_BYTES_Z;
//OR use a finer-grained view over the same data:
const z = structsAs8[i * SIZEOF_BYTES_ENTITY + OFFSET_BYTES_Z];

Great, it works. But what if our fake structs are greater than 64 bits (8 bytes) in length?
//now the new struct type we want to pull is 12x larger!
const SIZEOF_BYTES_ENTITY = 96;
const SIZEOF_WORDS_ENTITY = SIZEOF_BYTES_ENTITY / 8; //multiple 64-bit / 8-byte words.

const buffer = new ArrayBuffer(ENTITIES_COUNT * SIZEOF_BYTES_ENTITY);
const bigStructsAs64 = new Uint64Array(buffer);
//...populate our underlying buffer with some data... (not shown)

let index = 43; //to the entity we want

let bigStruct = bigStructsAs64.subarray(index * SIZEOF_ENTITY_WORDS);

.subarray() itself is a no-no as it creates a new TypedArray view which must then be GC'ed (possibly every animation frame). But at least we can be sure we are not doing this in JS code:
const bigStruct = new Uint64Array(SIZEOF_ENTITY_WORDS);

//copy out, one 64-bit word at a time:
for (int w = 0; w < SIZEOF_ENTITY_WORDS; w++)
{
    bigStruct[w] = bigStructsAs64[index * SIZEOF_ENTITY_WORDS + w];
}

Is there any faster method for pulling back large datablocks without using explicit JS loops?

Additional detail This question seems relevant in terms of overestimating the potential impact of the loop mentioned above.
My assumption thus far has been that native methods would perform this data-gathering operation more efficiently than loops written in JS. I'll need to run some tests and get back with results (pending).

May I ask if you considered using WASM instead?

@Dai That is on the cards, yes. But I would still like to know what is possible under JS directly, without involving C WASM modules for the time being.

We kinda need to know which JS engine you're using - V8? JavaScriptCore? Spidermonkey? And if this is running on constrained hardware where JIT isn't available.

Firefox doesn't use V8, soooo

@Pointy If you're unclear on concepts of copy-by-reference and copy-by-value, how JS operates vs C in that regard, how this impacts performance in terms of locality of reference and cache misses, how data access width affects data access rate, and how these concepts affect data pipelining in games, I suggest in-depth study of how game entity and particle simulation engines work. We can also chat and discuss in detail there, if you're interested to know, and providing I'm still awake.

If you want a 96-byte struct... I suppose you'd need to use 12x BigUint64-sized locals to avoid the overhead of a for loop - which means you'd end-up having to define your own C-style macro #define meta-language... at which point just use WASM. Alternatively, have you seen the new transferToFixedLength method?

Out of curiosity, and considering that V8 does loop-unwinding anyway, what does V8's profiler say about your for (int w = 0; w < SIZEOF_ENTITY_WORDS; w++) loop compared to a hand-unrolled version?

@Dai I'll have a look into transferToFixedLength now, thanks. Yes, ideally the loop would unroll if the struct sizes are constants, I'm never too sure whether V8 does that though, it seems according to this that the V8 devs skipped that optimisation for good reasons (code size in the instruction cache, for instance). So yes, that leaves manual unrolling for every possible struct size (not too many). Will make some tests tomorrow and return here.

Ah... due to creating a new array, transferToFixedLength() isn't going to work for at 60+ frames per second and many more calculations per frame: "creates new non-resizable ArrayBuffer with the same byte content as this buffer, then detaches this buffer." This seems to be a problem with several of TypedArrays methods, including .subarray(). A real pity these methods weren't thought out better, allowing one to pass in pre-existing arrays.

"The benefit here is that no matter how large the struct is, we write it back in a single line, and the compiler handles the copying needed to make that happen as quickly as possible." - that's great and all, but why are you copying the struct around at all instead of modifying the array in-place? That would be faster even in C. And just because you can "write it back in a single line" doesn't mean that it won't be slow or that its speed won't depend on the size of the struct.

"This is a performance-related question." - in that case, you'll need to post the actual code that you need optimised, and explain where and how and how often it is called. We can't help you with specifics otherwise, and general questions about "how to optimise C-like JavaScript" are way too broad. Also, https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/ applies

"regular JS rules and conventions are irrelevant here" - not really, as that is what JS engines will optimise for. So this should always be your first approach, and you should then benchmark it and find the bottlenecks and optimise them (or choose better data structures and algorithms). If you want to go so low-level as to optimise for cache lines, you really need to use WASM.

@Bergi There is nothing broad about the final question, which is "Is there a faster way to do this, or am I limited to a JS loop". The question isn't going to change.  'And just because you can "write it back in a single line" doesn't mean that it won't be slow or that its speed won't depend on the size of the struct.' Sure, although the likelihood of it being faster in native code that adresses such cases specifically, after decades of C compiler optimisations, is higher than if I naively implement similar in JS. P.S. The working example I provided suffices for the question asked.

@Bergi With regards to your other question about copying around struct, you make a fair point. Having said that, when your application relies on frequently copying and replacing state from frame to frame, there is no way around it, no matter how you look at it. Memberwise copies of e.g. 1+1+2 bytes are very unlikely to be faster than copying word-width blocks. My question pertains to whether, under the hood of V8 (and possibly Spidermonkey) there is a way to do this without using explicit Javascript code... and whether said approach may be faster, which is by no means guaranteed.

If you haven’t benchmarked subarray yet, I would do that and not immediately discard it as a candidate just because it creates an object. Anyway, are you looking for set?

@Ry- .set() would be perfect if it had parameters for both the source array start and length, AND the destination array start and length. So, unfortunately, almost but no cigar. This is a perfect example of API omissions that are causing me to question whether this approach is at all possible (while maintaining best possible performance). I'm leaning towards, "probably not".


Is there any faster method for pulling back large datablocks without using explicit JS loops?

If you have used
let bigStruct = bigStructsAs64.subarray(index * SIZEOF_ENTITY_WORDS, (index * SIZEOF_ENTITY_WORDS);

then you don't actually need to "pull it back", since the subarray method only creates another view on the same buffer. Modifying bigStruct directly writes to the underlying buffer of bigStructsAs64.
However if you have used
let bigStruct = bigStructsAs64.slice(index * SIZEOF_ENTITY_WORDS, (index+1) * SIZEOF_ENTITY_WORDS);

or another method to create a separate copy of the struct, then you can use the set method to efficiently copy a whole array into another typed array:
bigStructsAs64.set(bigStruct, index * SIZEOF_ENTITY_WORDS);

If you want to copy only part of a typed array into another type array, you should first get a .subarray(…) with the part that you want to copy over and then .set(…) that:
target.set(source.subarray(sourceStart, sourceStart + length), targetStart);


Right, and .subarray() allocates which is why it's not preferred. I cannot pre-allocate a separate sub-array for every one of thousands or hundreds of thousands of rays, particles, or entities, unfortunately. .slice() also allocates. In the end we're not getting out of this without allocations. At least with the loop, we avoid those allocations and the very frequent GC sweeps they incur, since we need to do what you describe above many times per frame at 60fps. So we see the difference between a C struct and what JS allows. If loop works, then it's to be preferred over allocs. Else C-WASM.

You asked to do it without a loop, not without allocations :-) I would hope that V8 can optimise away the allocation of the subarray that's only passed to  set, and even if it can't, it shouldn't give you much trouble since it will be garbage-collected very efficiently. I recommend to try it anyway - I would expect there's a cutoff at a certain size of the copied array where it's faster to construct an intermediate view and take advantage of the more efficient copying, than doing the individual assignments in a js loop.
